# A bound on the moment generating function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $|X|\le{K}$ for some $K>0$. I am trying to prove the following bound on the moment generating function of X:

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda{}X)]\le{}\exp(g(\lambda)\mathbb{E}[X^2])$$ where

$$g(\lambda):=\frac{\lambda^2\space{}/\space{}2}{1-|\lambda|K\space{}/\space{}3}$$
provided we have $|\lambda|<3\space{}/\space{}K.$

I've managed to show that if $X\le{}K$ a.e. then
 $$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda(X-\mathbb{E}[X]))]\le{\exp\bigg(\frac{\lambda^2/2\mathbb{E[X]}}{1-K\lambda/3}\bigg)}$$ for $\lambda\in{[0,3/K]}$. But can't see where to go from here or if this is even the right direction.

p.s. I got to that inequality by considering the function $h(\lambda):=2\big(\frac{e^X-X-1}{2}\big)$

Comment: A ‘bound on’ is not a bumblebee! ;--)

Comment: Apologies, edited accordingly

Comment: You don't have to apologise, it happens to all of us. Are you French, per chance?

Comment: No, just dyslexic :')

Comment: The given bound is incorrect. For example, let us take X = 1/3 and K=1 then $\text{E}[exp(\lambda X)] = e^{\lambda/3}$ and the bound is $exp(g(\lambda)/9) = exp(\frac{\lambda^2}{6(3-|\lambda|)})$. You can see by taking $\lambda=1$ that $e^{1/3} > e^{1/12}$.